# How to instantiate model Angular 2

Tags: forms, typescript, angular, model

I'm creating a very basic Angular 2 Application with the purpose of CRUD products. I have a CreateProductComponent but I'm having trouble instantiating the model that I wan't to use on my view. I'm getting this error:

[image]

This is my code:

create-product.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { Product } from '../product'
import { ProductService } from '../product.service'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-create-product',
    templateUrl: 'create-product.html',
    styleUrls: ['create-product.css'],
})
export class CreateProductComponent {

    model: new Product(1,'2',1); <- error on this line

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

    addProduct() {        

        //this.productService.addProduct(this.product);
    }
}
```

product.ts

```
export class Product {

    constructor(
        public ID: number,
        public Name: string,
        public Price: number
    ) { }   
}
```

Ideally, I would like to create an empty product, or a product with defaul values so that when a form in the view is filled with the product data this data is passed down to the product. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're syntax is a little off. You should be using any of the following:

This creates a property with an instantiated value of `Product`.

```
export class CreateProductComponent {

    // Define model, declare type, and assign/instantiate.
    model = new Product(1,'2',1);

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
}
```

Or this one, which defines the property `model` as a type of `Product` but doesn't assign it a value. Instead it's assigned in the constructor.

```
export class CreateProductComponent {

    // Define model, declare type
    model: Product;

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
        this.model = new Product(1,'2',1);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could even be more explicit, even though it is not required as the types can easily be inferred.

```
export class CreateProductComponent {

    // Define model, declare type, and assign/instantiate.
    model: Product = new Product(1,'2',1);

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
}
```

There is some great documentation [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) as well as a [REPL playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) which I highly suggest using.

Comment: Thanks it works! But should I instantiate the product with these meaningless values? If I were programming on backend I would create an empty Product (var product = new Product();) and then I would assign the values sent by the user (product.name = name; product.price = price). How can I do that in this case?

Comment: @JoãoPaiva, no problem - happy to help. I would personally go with the second option I posted. `model: Product`, you get a property that has a defined type and you can check if it is null easily by using standard JavaScript expressions.

Answer (score 2):

In typescript terminology **':' means you are declaring a type for a variable you have defined.**

**'=' means you are assigning a value to your variable.**

But here what you did is instead of assigning a value you are trying to declare a value (which is not correct according to syntax)

so either you can directly assign a value like

```
model = new Product(1,'2',1);
```

or else you can first declare a type for your variable and then assign a value in either of these two ways (I personally prefer this way)

```
model: Product = new Product(1,'2',1);
```

or

```
model: Product;
model = new Product(1,'2',1);
```

Comment: this clarified some basic concepts for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
model = new Product(1,'2',1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an field in CreateProductComponent. Use '=' instead of ':' like

`model = new Product(1,'2',1); <- error on this line`